# rewriting a floating point sum from Python to Rust

Tags: rust, rounding, floating

I've been trying to rewrite the code below for summing floating point numbers while minimizing the rounding errors, but I found it pretty hard to do in Rust.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I attach my non-working Rust attempt

```py
def msum(iterable):
    "Full precision summation using multiple floats for intermediate values"
    # Rounded x+y stored in hi with the round-off stored in lo.  Together
    # hi+lo are exactly equal to x+y.  The inner loop applies hi/lo summation
    # to each partial so that the list of partial sums remains exact.
    # Depends on IEEE-754 arithmetic guarantees.  See proof of correctness at:
    #www-2.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/quake/public/papers/robust-arithmetic.ps

    partials = []               # sorted, non-overlapping partial sums
    for x in iterable:
        i = 0
        for y in partials:
            if abs(x) < abs(y):
                x, y = y, x
            hi = x + y
            lo = y - (hi - x)
            if lo:
                partials[i] = lo
                i += 1
            x = hi
        partials[i:] = [x]
    return sum(partials, 0.0)
```

The code below is what I have in Rust so far, but it's not working yet

```rust
fn inexact_sum(v: &Vec<f64>) -> f64 {
    let mut partials: Vec<f64> = vec![];
    for x in v {

        let mut i: usize = 0;
        let mut hi: f64;
        let mut lo: f64;

        for y in partials.clone().iter() {
            hi = x + y;
            lo = if x.abs() < y.abs() {
                y - (hi - x)
            } else {
                x - (hi - y)
            };
            if lo != 0.0_f64 {
                partials[i] = lo;
                i += 1;
            }
            let x = hi;
            println!("x = {}, y = {}", x, y);
        }
        partials.truncate(i);
        partials.push(hi);
    }
    partials.iter().fold(0.0_f64, |a, b| a + b)
}
```

EDIT: Thinking about it a bit more, indeed, the error the compiler gave me `` error: use of possibly uninitialized variable: `hi` `` is indeed useful.  I should have paid more attention to it.  The point is that the first time the loop does not execute at all, so hi does not get initialized.  So if I change `partials.push(hi);` to `partials.push(*x);` the code compiles and runs but it does not give the right answer.

Comment: "but it's not working yet" is not helpful. In what way is it not working?

Comment: @Veedrac Sorry, I should have given more details.  It seems to me that the Python version modifies an iterator while iterating over it.  This is in general considered bad practice, and I assume it is a source of problems in Rust.  Anyway, the error message I get with the stable `rustc` is ``error: use of possibly uninitialized variable: `hi` [E0381]``, which is strange since `hi` is definitely initialized and is defined outside the scope of the inner `for` loop.

Comment: And what does "but it does not give the right answer" refer to? Be *specific*.

Comment: `partials` is an empty vector during the first iteration; thus the inner loop will not run and `hi` will have never been set to any value. In general, even if `partials` had some initial value, the compiler cannot track that (this is why it says *possibly* uninitialized) and you have to handle the case where `partials` might have been empty.

Comment: It seems to work. 
https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ad9bf3273612a651da91&version=stable
You was close. But I do not see any difference in precision

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? I think you did not mean to clone the `partials` array but found that you needed to in order to satisfy the borrow checker; if you try to use the code:

```
for y in partials.iter() {
    ...
    partials[i] = lo;
```

The borrow checker will complain:

```
<anon>:13:17: 13:25 error: cannot borrow `partials` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable [E0502]
```

I got around this by using an index into the array instead:

```
for j in 0..partials.len() {
    let mut y = partials[j];
```

Then you are not cloning the whole array of partials each time around the outer loop! Since the `partials` array can be modified whilst iterating through it, taking a clone first means you will end up with the old value of `y` instead of the new one if it has been modified.

```
use std::mem;

fn msum(v: &[f64]) -> f64 {
    let mut partials: Vec<f64> = vec![];
    for x in v {
        let mut x = *x;
        let mut i = 0;
        for j in 0..partials.len() {
            let mut y = partials[j];
            if x.abs() < y.abs() { mem::swap(&mut x, &mut y) }
            let hi = x + y;
            let lo = y - (hi - x);
            if lo != 0.0 {
                partials[i] = lo;
                i += 1;
            }
            x = hi;
        }
        partials.truncate(i);
        partials.push(x);
    }
    partials.iter().fold(0., |a, b| a + b)
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1.234, 1e16, 1.234, -1e16];
    println!("{}",msum(&v));
}
```

[Playpen](http://is.gd/3fyxBk)

Comment: @Shepmaster Fixed, hope explanation is clear enough now.

Comment: Looking great! Too bad I have only one upvote to give!